# PHP simpleXML: parse specific attribute value of multiple entries

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML:

```
<doc>
    <str name="segment">20170913064727</str>
    <str name="digest">427522d5ceb605f87755c909deac698a</str>
    <str name="title">AMS Site</str>
<doc>
```

I want to parse it and to save the value of "title" to the variable $ergTitle (that would be "AMS Site").

I have the following PHP code:

```
foreach($data->result->doc as $dat) {
    foreach ($dat->str as $att) {
        foreach ($att->attributes() as $a => $b) {
            echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n" . '<br>';
            if ($b=='title') {
                echo "OK";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which results to:

```
name="segment" 
name="digest" 
name="id" 
name="title" 
OKname="url" 
name="content"
```

But how can I now get the value of name="title" and save it to my variable?

*Goal*: I want to print the content of "content", "url", "title" and so on (its for a result site of a search query.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over the element's *attributes*. In your loop, the element value is in the `$dat` variable. In this example, I had to remove one `foreach()` loop because of the sample XML:

```
<?php
$data = simplexml_load_file("a.xml");
foreach($data->str as $dat) {
    foreach ($dat->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        echo $a,'="',$b,'"';
        if ($b=='title') {
            echo "right one";
        }
    }
    echo " -> ".$dat."<br>";
}

/* result */
name="segment" -> 20170913064727
name="digest" -> 427522d5ceb605f87755c909deac698a
name="title" right one -> AMS Site
```

If you want to put the title when you find it in a variable, use the same variable inside the loop:

```
<?php
$data = simplexml_load_file("a.xml");
foreach($data->str as $dat) {
    foreach ($dat->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        if ($b=='title') {
            $title = $dat;
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo "Title: ".$dat; // Title: AMS Site
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the structure of your XML, it might be easier to just loop over the `<str>` elements and build up an array mapping the **name** attribute to the content.

```
$dat = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$attributes = [];

foreach ($dat->str as $str) { 
  $attributes[(string) $str['name']] = (string) $str;
}
```

You could then access the "title" element under `$attributes['title']` (or assign it to your `$ergTitle` variable, etc).